# Why does multiprocessing.Queue have a small delay while (apparently) multiprocessing.Pipe does not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Documentation for [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) points out that there's a bit of a delay from when an item is enqueued until it's pickled representation is flushed to the underlying Pipe.  Apparently though you can enqueue an item straight into a Pipe (it doesn't say otherwise and implies that's the case).

Why doesn't the Pipe need - or have - the same background thread to do the pickling?  And is that the same reason that there's no similar delay when talking to a `multiprocessor.SyncManager.Queue`?

(Bonus question: What does the documentation mean when it says "After putting an object on an empty queue there may be an *infinitesimal* delay ..."?  I've taken calculus; I know what *infinitesimal* means, and that meaning doesn't seem to fit here.  So what is it talking about?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write to a `Pipe`, the *current* thread **blocks** until the write completes.  There is therefore no delay (or rather, the calling thread can’t observe any), but it’s possible to **deadlock**; `Pipe` is a lower-level tool than `Queue`.

The situation with `SyncManager.Queue` is simply that all requests to the manager are **synchronized** such that the process that pushes an object cannot then observe it to still be empty (absent a pop).

Meanwhile, the “infinitesimal” delay merely means a thread scheduling delay rather than the (possibly much larger) time to write the entire object: it’s enough for it to have **started** so as to establish that the `Queue` is not empty.  The pushing thread can nonetheless win the race and observe it still lacking the object “already pushed”.

Comment: These details on whether the calling (i.e., pushing) thread blocks or not are critical to knowing how to use these different constructs effectively, yet aren't covered in the documentation.  (Example of when they're critical: time-sensitive streams of data, e.g., video frame processing, where judder counts.)

Comment: @davidbak: The assumption is that the caller blocks unless otherwise specified—as it is for `Queue` because of its deadlock-avoidance strategy.  For performance, the IPC is probably more important than any thread switch.

Comment: OK! From now on I'll read the docs with that assumption in mind.

Comment: In which way is a `Pipe` prone to deadlock?

Comment: @moi: Two processes that each write to the other using a pipe (or `Pipe`) may each wait forever for the other to read the first part of its message.