# Why does `multiprocessing.Queue` use a feeder thread?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue):

> When a process first puts an item on the queue a feeder thread is started which transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe.

Why is that? `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` gets along without such a thread. Is it just so that a writer doesn't have to wait for the object to be pickled? Or is there another reason?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474511/why-does-multiprocessing-queue-have-a-small-delay-while-apparently-multiproces) seems to be related, but the answer given there does not help me much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that without a background feeder thread (like in `SimpleQueue`), `put` will block if the underlying `Pipe`'s buffer is full. `Pipe(duplex=False)` is implemented using `os.pipe` with a [capacity of 16 pages (since Linux 2.6.35)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html). With a feeder thread (like in `Queue`), the writer does not have to wait for the underlying pipe.